# Can a sand box mitigate the effect of a buffer overflow.

Tags: security, linux-kernel, selinux, seccomp

I have to do some research about Sand Box process. But I cannot understand how a sandbox can mitigate a buffer overflow. Let's say I have my server application ( a FTP server) this is affect by a buffer overflow which can be exploited remotely.

How sandbox as  Vx32, Janus ostia can stop the inject code from accessing the file system?

Answer (score 0):

They don't give any of the code in the sandbox permissions to access the file system at all. If a buffer overflow happens, that overflow happens inside the sandboxed program, so the program in question is still sandboxed.